# changing ownership not working

Tags: php, file, wamp, chown

I am trying to create and change the ownership of a file in `windows` environment ( `WAMP`). My files are as below :

```
<?php
$my_file = 'myfile.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$path = "c:\wamp\www\\".$my_file;
$user_name = "Nitish D";
chown($path, $user_name);
?>
```

Though the file `myfile.txt` is created, wheen I checked its details it shows its `owner` as `Administrators`. How can I change the `owner` to my `$user_name` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case a file that you're trying to change ownership on, belongs to the other user, you can not change it to yourself, unless you run the command as `administrator` *(that user)* or `root` user!

Besides your username contains spaces - that's not allowed on NIX systems. Username should follow the rule:

```
([a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30})
```

Moreover the username must exist. Try checking if user that you're refering to is really registered:

```
cat /etc/passwd |grep username
```